# Attribute sending '<' instead of Integer, cannot figure out why

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm trying to register a Follow User in my DB, but I'm getting the following error:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '<' for column 'followed_id' at row 1

I already got that for some reason my input is sending < instead of Integer. I did a dump {{of the variable}} and is displaying the correct value (an integer, which is a user_id), but when sending info, it's sending something else.

I cannot understand why this is happening though. Instead of sending a variable I sent a number and it worked perfectly.

This is the Blade part where I send the info to the controller

```
                            <a href="{!! route('user.follow', ['id' => '{{$post->user_id}}']) !!}">
                        Follow User! {{$post->name}} {{$post->user_id}}</a>
```

Im pretty sure Im not missing anything, I cannot figure out why its sending < instead of the integer.

This is my Controller

```
    function followUser($user_id)
{
  follower::create([
  'follower_id' => Auth::user()->id,
  'followed_id' => $user_id,
]);
return redirect()->route('posts');
```

This is my DB

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('post');
        $table->foreign('user_id')
          ->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('followers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('follower_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('followed_id');
        $table->foreign('follower_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

This is the Controller that send the Object into the view

```
function allPosts()
{
  $todos = DB::table('posts')
                ->select('posts.post','posts.id','posts.user_id','users.name')
                ->join('users','users.id','=','posts.user_id')
                ->get();

return view('/posts', [
    'all' => $all,
    ]);
```

Comment: Can you post the entire error? This should contain an sql part with the syntax that isn't working.

Comment: `{!! ... {{ ...` In your `<a>` tag is invalid, that's like having `<?php ... <?php` (or similar); basically you're opening a php tag inside an already opened php tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change this line: 
`<a href="{!! route('user.follow', ['id' => '{{$post->user_id}}']) !!}">`

to this: 
`<a href="{!! route('user.follow', ['id' => $post->user_id]) !!}">`

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly, it's logging the information into the DB. Now Im getting Route not defined, even if I have return redirect()->route('posts'); and Route::get('/posts','PostsController@allPosts');

I will investigate further because this has happened before when I try to redirect to the same view Im coming from, not sure why though.
Thanks again for the clarification!

Comment: you are welcome :) have you tried this? `return redirect('posts');`

Comment: That worked. Im still learning, will have to red more documentation. Always been using the other format. Thanks, solved a lot of my problem with that. Was having a nightmare naming routes left and right

Comment: final tip: if you wanna use `redirect()->route('something')` you have to define a name for your route, just like this: `Route::get('/posts','PostsController@allPosts')->name('something');`